# How to adjust the tolerance when showing vertices with the V key (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, editing, vertices

When in the editing mode in ArcMap, it is possible to approach the mouse cursor close enough to a feature and press the V key. This will show the vertices of the feature.

[image]

However, you need to move the cursor quite close (I believe the default tolerance is 10 pixels) to be able to show the vertices. I want to be able to quickly see vertices of features without moving my mouse cursor too much.

Is it possible to adjust this tolerance value? Editing the snapping tolerance doesn't affect the "vertex show tolerance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have searched more first...

This setting is available in the AdvancedArcMapSettings utility which can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\Utilities` folder. Go to the Editor tab and adjust the value for the option Search tolerance for drawing vertices of features. The default is 5px.